# Read all remaining bytes in a file

Tags: java, file-io, io

I know I can read all bytes of a file using `Files.readAllBytes`. But what if I have already read some of it and I want to read the remaining bytes. I know I could define a `byte[]` and loop over all bytes using `FileReader.read` but I'd like to avoid looping if possible and read all the remaining bytes in one go.

Comment: How do you want the data? in a byte[] or a byte buffer? or do you want it in some other form?

Comment: Either of them, as long as it's read only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [InputStream#skip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29) that skips over and discards n bytes of data from this input stream.

Use [File#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) that returns the length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

---

Alternatively try with [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.read()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) that reads bytes from an input stream.

Comment: 1. I don't wanna discard so no skipping. 2. `File.length` doesn't help, since I may not know how much I have already read. 3. I'd need to path the remaining length, how do I get that? On the other hand I'd like to stick with the standard API but if that's the only way, I have no choice.

Comment: There is no harm of trying it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no read operation from a file which guarantees to read the entire remaining content in a single call. If you have FileInputStream, you can get a FileChannel, which will tell you the current [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position%28%29). You will also know the size, so you can calculate how much data is left. You can then size a byte[] or ByteBuffer for that remaining size and read the content. But the read must be in a loop accounting for the fact that an individual read call may not read all of the requested data.

If you have a file channel, you could [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) the rest of the file, which will give you access to the rest of the file as a ByteBuffer. How you are planning on accessing this data is important, however, as this is a direct byte buffer and the memory utilized is in native space. Any use from the within the jvm itself will require crossing the jni boundary.